# How to get eclipse content assist working in XML files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I have started creating the Spring web application where I need to mention the spring classes in the XML configuration files, for ex, the deployment descriptor (web.xml) where I need to mention the DispatcherServlet class of Spring.

What I am looking for is, I want eclipse to show me the list of packages/classes when I type org.springframework..., like we do in the Java editor. I have googled to find out, but no luck. I am sure there would be plugins available. Can any of you please share me on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on a spring project, I'd recommend installing the SpringToolSuite (STS). The info page is here: http://spring.io/tools

Since you already have an Eclipse instance that you are working with, you should go with the update sites: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/

(Make sure to use the correct update site for the Eclipse version you are using.)

Not only does STS include all tools for XML editing, but it also includes special tools for editing your Spring application files.

Comment: in addition this I would like to mention that the advanced XML editing features of the Spring Tool Suite are targeted towards the Spring XML config files, not the web.xml.

Comment: @Andrew, Thanks for reply. I am already aware of STS, but did not use it as I use different technology and thought of sticking with Eclipse. Is there any plugin available to pull the class from the classpath and perform the content assist in Eclipse?

Comment: STS *is* eclipse. It's just a set of plugins. You can either download a complete instance of STS, or just use the update site to grab the Spring IDE plugins. In your case, I'd recommend the latter.